# ошибка Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, html

Написал скрипт для перезагрузки страницы:

```
    header('Location:lottery.php');//строка 82
    exit;
```

Выскочила ошибка - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at V:\home\mySite\www\lottery.php:204) in V:\home\mySite\www\lottery.php on line 82

строка 204, как в ошибке:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

пробелов перед < ? нет, искал 100500 раз...

Comment: Вы отсылаете контент раньше заголовка, что нельзя делать.

Comment: @Other как это? я хочу обовить страницу после нажатия кнопки

Comment: @shumik_UA, Почитайте дубликат, там описано как избежать этой проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка выскакивает, когда перед header() есть какой-то вывод. Если это строка 82, то вывод может быть где угодно. Тут без вариантов на страницу попадает какой-то символ, пробел, html код, может какие-то заголовки были уже посланы. Попробуй сделать exit; перед строкой 82 и по ctrl+U посмотреть исходники что попадает на страницу. Для нормальной перезагрузки страницы она должна быть полностью пуста.